# Synology RAID and backup

Tags: backup, raid, nas, storage, synology

I'm researching into buying a Synology NAS solution with 4 bay hdd for a small office (2 users, sharing files, backup) and I can't find if is possible to have two of the hard drives in RAID 1 and the other two also in RAID 1 and function as a backup storage. So I would write my data on the first two hard drives and schedule a backup once a day/week/etc on the other two.
Or have just two hdds in RAID and the other two be separate back-up hdds.
Also I know that the Synology NAS devices have the function to backup on the same device (different volume). Are there any limitations for this function?

Other solutions would be 2 devices, each with 2 bays, but I would prefer a single device. Or a 2 bay NAS with external backup (external harddrive).

Also, I read about QNAP devices, but I didn't tested their QTS operating system. From screenshots I saw that it's similar with the Synology DSM. Is it comparable?

Comment: you can't create two separate volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create the set up as you desire. I would recommend creating 2 separate disk groups each with their own RAID configuration.

> Disk Group Disk groups are composed of one or more hard drives
>   combined into a single data partition. You can think of disk groups as
>   the foundation on which one or more volumes or iSCSI LUN can be built.
>   Disk groups provide greater flexibility, allowing you to do the
>   following: Choose from various RAID types, depending on the number of
>   hard drives installed. Create a single, large volume, or create
>   several volumes with customizable storage capacity.

TO do this:
Add your disks to the machine
Install DSM
Open storage manager and navigate to DiskGroup
On there create the disk group by adding 2 drives and adding the level of RAID you require.

Then rinse and repeat for the other 2 drives.

On mine I have created 2 disk groups and added them as 2 separate SHR configurations check out the photo:

[Separate RAID configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpLUC.jpg)

This allows the setup as you have described. DSM is very powerful and would allow all sorts of configs.

HOWEVER -

I would recommend looking at something that Synology use called SHR-2/SHR. These are more efficient for space vs redundancy and easier to manage.

A handy calculator for RAID spaces etc:
https://www.synology.com/en-uk/support/RAID_calculator

I think your DR solution needs more thought though, if it's redundancy and backup you're looking for best practice dictates that you need a proper backup solution, look up bullet proof backups. So first local & then offsite (cloud, physical USB that is taken away etc)

Questions to answer are:
What happens if the synology box is stolen? Backups would go with it.
What if the site the synology box is destroyed / inaccessible?

Anyhow, let me know if this helps and if you need help setting this up more than happy to help offline too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the off-site backup I want to use the cloud sync feature of Synology and sync all data into a Google Drive / Dropbox account.
Also I'm thinking of using two external drives that I would use to backup and take off premises alternatively.
Hanselman is describing this best: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheComputerBackupRuleOfThree.aspx

Comment: No worries. Yep that's exactly it with the backup solution just to make it 'as redundant as can be'... Good luck!